# При клике по иконке расширения для Opera не выполняется вывод текста в консоли

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, opera

Почему?

Содержимое файла manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "name",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "description",
    
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    
    "permissions": ["tabs"],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icon.png"
        }
    }
}
```

Содержимое файла background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    console.log('text');
});
```

Comment: Я не уверен, но может объект `chrome` предназначен для Chromium-подобных браузеров?

Answer (score 0):

Вывод отображается в отладочной консоли, которую можно открыть на странице opera://extensions:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]